# Multiple Device Densities and Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm struggling with a custom control and getting it to render properly on different devices. I have a map (a map of a state) which I am rendering on the screen.

My drawables looks like this:
**drawable

drawable-sw320dp

drawable-sw360dp**

The problem is, there are 2 phones I have access to (my Samsung Galaxy 6 and my wife's Sony XPeria Compact).

2 very different phones. They both use the map which I put in the 360 folder.
But the map is far too big for the Sony. Even if I drop 360 to 350, both phones use the 350 folder.

A few more stats about the phones:
**Samsung**
Width in Pixels: 1440
Height in Pixels: 2560
Width in Dp: 360
Height in Dp: 640

**Sony**
Width in Pixels: 720
Height in Pixels: 1184
Width in Dp: 360
Height in Dp: 592

How can I structure my drawable folders, such that the Sony uses the smaller map png?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use configuration qualifiers, structuring your `Resources` folder like this and defining every configuration folder:

> drawable-ldpi Resources folder for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi).
>   drawable-mdpi Resources folder for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is
>   the baseline density.) 
>   drawable-hdpi Resources folder for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi). 
>   drawable-xhdpi    Resources folder for extra-high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi). 
>   drawable-xxhdpi   Resources folder for extra-extra-high-density (xxhdpi) screens (~480dpi). 
>   drawable-xxxhdpi  Resources folder for extra-extra-extra-high-density (xxxhdpi) uses (~640dpi).

Keeping in mind that the ratio for the assets between these configurations is:

```
ldpi | mdpi | hdpi | xhdpi | xxhdpi | xxxhdpi
0.75 | 1    | 1.5  | 2     | 3      | 4
```

Comment: That appears to have worked. I was trying to achieve the same thing using the width-based naming scheme. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

[You can refer to this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html?).

> How can I structure my drawable folders, such that the Sony uses the smaller map png?

Yes, you need a smaller map picture for the Sony, and a bigger map for Samsung.

You can use `Resources.DisplayMetrics.Ydpi` and `Resources.DisplayMetrics.Xdpi` to get value of `dpi` in your two phones. And refer to the quote in @hichame.yessou's answer to  choose which folder to put bigger map, which folder to put smaller map.

If you don't have two picture, you can adaptive the UI programmatically, please refer to [TypedValue.applyDimension](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#applyDimension(int,%20float,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics)